# Regular expression to extract strings after "/" in r

Tags: regex, r, string

I have a vector of length N and each of its elements has the following structure:

```
"Country/state/municipality"
```

I'd like to extract each component separately:

```
"Country" "state" "municipality"
```

I know the `str_extract()` function may work but I have problems with the regular expression to get the string components so I'd really appreciate your help.

Comment: A simple `strsplit(x, "/", fixed = TRUE)` should do it.

Comment: or a simple `c(dirname(dirname(x)), basename(dirname(x)), basename(x))`

Comment: @RichardScriven - we don't need `fixed=TRUE`, do we? `/` is not a regex character AFAIK.

Comment: @jbaums - Not sure if it's a regex character or not, but since it's a fixed split I think it makes things faster.  Good question though, I don't know if `strsplit()` avoids the regex engine with non regex characters.